Angular Zoneless - Prevent change detection for template listeners
Trying zoneless experimental feature in Angular, when updating a signal value, I would like to re-render only the views related to the signal.
Given this example :
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ChildComponent],
  template: `
    <div>{{ getDate() }}</div>
    <app-child></app-child>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  getDate(): string {
    return new Date().toString();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div>{{ getDate() }}</div>
    <button type="button" (click)="reset()"></button>
    <div>
      {{ value() }}
    </div>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  value = signal(0);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.value.update((v) => v + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }

  reset() {
    this.value.set(0);
  }

  getDate(): string {
    return new Date().toString();
  }
}

I get the expected behavior when updating the value in setInterval. Only the child component view is refreshed (the printed date in AppComponent doesn't change).
When I click on the reset button, a change detection is triggered over the whole app (so the printed date in AppComponent is updated).
As I only update a signal value, I would like to prevent this change detection and only re-render the ChildComponent view which depends on this signal.
Is there a way to prevent this change detection cycle for template listeners like click, mouseup, mousedown etc. when running Angular in zoneless mode ?

Right now there is no way around this, this behavior is hard coded in the framework itself.
This is something that must be changed at the framework level and the Angular team is looking into this.

This is disappointing because signals have a reference to their live consumer views, so they can refresh them when their value is updated. As a result, change detection mechanism seems to be useless in most case. Maybe there is still a lack of integration between signals and angular forms.

Like I said, this is optimization the team is aware of and will likely address it in the near future.
